# How to use selenium along with scrapy to automate the process?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, scrapy

I came to know at one point you need to use webtoolkits like selenium to automate the scraping.

How I will be able to click the next button on google play store in order to scrape the reviews for my college purpose only !!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
import time


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()


class FooSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'foo'

    start_urls = ["https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gaana&hl=en"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.download_delay = 0.25
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chrm\chromedriver.exe")
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(60) # 

    def parse(self,response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@class="single-review"]/div[@class="review-header"]')
        items = []
        for i in range(0,200):
            time.sleep(20)
            button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]/div[2]/div/div")
            button.click()
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(30)    
            for site in sites:
                item = Product()

                item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="review-info"]/span[@class="author-name"]/a/text()').extract()
                yield item
```

I have updated my code and it is only giving me repeative 40 items again and again.whats wrong with my for loop?

**It seems that the source code which is being updated is not passed to the xpath thats why it is returning with same 40 items**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like that:

```
from scrapy import CrawlSpider
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class FooSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'foo'
    allow_domains = 'foo.com'
    start_urls = ['foo.com']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.download_delay = 0.25
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(60)

    def parse_foo(self.response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)  # load response to the browser
        button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("path") # find 
        # the element to click to
        button.click() # click
        time.sleep(1) # wait until the page is fully loaded
        source = self.browser.page_source # get source of the loaded page
        sel = Selector(text=source) # create a Selector object
        data = sel.xpath('path/to/the/data') # select data
        ...
```

It's better not to wait for a fixed amount of time, though. So instead of  `time.sleep(1)`, you can use one of the approaches described here http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html.

Comment: It is still not loading the url in the browser

Comment: browser open but no url gets entered in it

Comment: Try `webdriver.Chrome()` instead of `webdriver.Firefox()`. Firefox didn't work in my case, too.

Comment: I have updated my code by taking help from your but its giving me repeative 40 items again and again what to do?

Comment: @JohnDene Please accept my answer if it helped you and create a separate question for your current problem and describe it in details.

Comment: Isn't this downloading the file twice? Once via scapy once via selenium?

Comment: `sel = Selector(text=source)` that Selector object, does that belong to Python, Scrapy, or?!